# How much do teaching responsibilities hinder a researcher at a small university?

Tags: publications, career-path

I would like to consider physics (theory) or math. I have two questions, but in general I would like to understand more about the following.

- If a researcher joins the faculty of a small (not top-research) university, will his/her administrative or teaching responsibilities be much greater than those of a researcher at a top university?
- If so, does this hinder his/her research development to an appreciable degree? Or perhaps this is not worth worrying about, and a good scholar will find a way to produce good research regardless of circumstances.

Any perspectives or evidence would be appreciated.

Comment: So what's the ratio? 90% research, 10% teaching? or 80/20, or 70/30 or 30/70 etc...

Comment: I don't know. That ratio (at large vs small universities) would be helpful info, if anyone could provide it.

Comment: This is so broad - perhaps you should provide some focus to your question ie narrow it down - as it is even a good answer is being commented as having bits missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the extreme case I'm acquainted with, some teaching-focused Universities give most professors 4/4-4/3-3/3 loads (that is 3-4 3-credit classes to teach every semester, with sometimes an extra class requiring to be taught in the summer/interim periods), more or less zero research funding, no lab, few to no graduate students, and very few or no TAs/graders for the classes they do teach. The key factor isn't really size-alone, though, as a bigger R1 can have similar conditions to a smaller R1.

As a direct comparison, I've known professors a teaching institution to teach a 200 student introduction class with no graders or assistants whatsoever (about all they get is access to an office that will process Scantron bubble sheets for them), for a subject that in an R1 University would have had 4 graduate students and half a dozen or so graders assigned. At the same time, the R1 professor might have a 2/2 or 3/2 load, with the occasionally teaching buyout/buydown so they could teach less in some semesters, or get extra credit to prepare teaching a new class; professors at teaching Universities much more rarely have any class reductions, and often preparing a new course gets no extra consideration - prep is just part of the job.

In the extreme, the teaching workload at a teaching University is so much greater than at a research University that the only answer is "yes, this absolutely effects research output". As a specific example from a few fields I'm familiar with (especially computing, math, psychology), in a single field where R1 faculty would be expected to average at least 3 publications in notable peer-reviewed venues every year, professors at a teaching University may be expected to produce a total of 3 papers over 5-7 years to be able to obtain tenure. The average acceptable research output of a teaching-focused University would not be sufficient to allow most faculty to survive a 3-year review in good standing at an R1.

These are the extremes, comparing a high-production large (40,000+ undergraduate students) R1 University with a smaller teaching-focused University (<10,000 students, only a few graduate degree programs), as I have personal experience knowing faculty working at both types of institution. There are lots of institutions in-between, however, and I am not familiar enough with the recent experiences of community-college faculty to comment there (for those not familiar with the term, this usually means institutions that focus on 2-year degrees, usually do not offer any 4 year degrees, and basically never offer graduate degrees).

For instance, the group of Universities sometimes called R2 Universities - and some liberal arts colleges which still have high research expectations - often fall somewhere in the middle of all this, in terms of research production and teaching loads/support. Variation among this group, I'm told, varies widely, and some R2s seem to aim to be R1s and offer better support, some offer less support yet demand more research anyway, etc. YMMV, in other words.

I should note that while teaching loads and average research outputs are closely tied, they are not a universal rule. A few professors I've known have still managed to produce consistent influential research programs at teaching institutions - however, the ones I know about ended up leaving or gearing up to try to leave such institutions for others that would provide them more research support and lower teaching loads. There is a strong opt-in factor, as well, as professors who want to do a lot of research generally refuse to even apply to teaching-focused positions, where as professors who will apply to such positions often either care less about churning out publications or end up deciding that they would rather focus on teaching and training than writing pub after pub.

Note that funding for research itself varies extremely between institutions. Some people don't actually need much funding beyond salary for their research, so of course in some fields this doesn't matter much. But in other fields the difference is extreme. Between institutions within the same field the startup packages that can be used on equipment and hiring (post docs, students, services, etc.) by new faculty range from $500k+ to $0 (yes, zero). I received more research funding and assistance as a new graduate student than most of the professors I know at a teaching institution got when they started as faculty.

Finally, the last big difference in small and large was very well pointed out by Buffy in another answer. In a large University I know a half-dozen people who have interest about a specific narrow sub-topic in my field - at a small institution, I could find no one who had experience in my sub-field at all and no one had even heard of the largest conferences in the field. This can make local collaboration difficult, which depending on your topics and work style can hinder your productivity overall as well.

In the end, the places that produce the largest amount of research (by any measure you care to use) do so for many, many reasons that can be hard to parse out or replicate outside of those places - but teaching load, funding, and administrative support are big factors no matter how you look at it.

Comment: The R1, R2, R3 classification only applies to U.S. schools, it seems and looking at the list of R1 universities I would expect huge differences in teaching load. When looking at other countries, things become even messier. Although this answer touches upon a lot of important points, I am not sure how well it answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have a heavier teaching load at most small universities. Such places usually have teaching as their primary mission. Teaching is usually required at large US universities as well, unless you are completely grant funded. But that isn't the only issue.

At a small institution it is much harder to develop a synergistic core of researchers. Even if there are, say five math faculty, they are not especially likely to have the same research interests or be focused on the same field.

Things are a bit easier in the last couple of decades with advances in communication, but you still aren't likely to see deep research seminars in a topic of interest to you at a small place.

Also, note that in the US, most faculty are actually working at smaller, primarily teaching, institutions than large research universities. If you look at, for example, the list of colleges in a given state, say New York, you will find only a few large institutions and many, many small ones. It is a bit complicated since some private research institutions are actually fairly small. In those, the mission is primarily research or it is balanced.

Comment: Other challenges in doing research at smaller universities include lack of library resources (needed journals often aren't available at the library), lack of institutional support for lab supplies, hazardous materials handling, etc., lack of computing facilities, lack of travel funds, and usually very limited startup packages.

Comment: @Buffy It seems that at top-tier universities, faculty interests still don't align (in math and theoretical physics)-- at least judging from output of collaborative papers among faculty at the same school. So what is this synergistic core of researchers? Do you mean good grad students/ post docs assisting a PI? Or just a general environment which is more conducive to research?

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by addressing differences in grad student support (i.e. at a smaller university you are less likely to have a TA or grader)

Comment: I studied math in two large universities. In both of them there were high level continuing seminars led by superstars and attended by two or three other faculty and half a dozen students. It was a source of problems and solutions for both faculty and students. I worked in smaller places and was always the only one with interests similar to my own other than a few students.

Comment: Are you sure researchers at Caltech (small) have a higher teaching load? A position at CUNY (a teaching institution) provides access to a huge synergistic core of researchers and seminars in the NY area. I think at the end of the day, one can only look at each institution separately. Teaching 1/1 is great, everything beyond 2/2 bad. Finding nearby researchers/seminars on your topic is ideal and independent of size. Teaching institutions are great if they pay so much that you don't even need research funds....

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what the researcher was hired for.  If (as usual) a researcher was hired for equal parts of three tasks (teaching, research, service), then YES they will have less time for research than someone hired for research only.

But note: Most scholars wind up at much lower-rated programs than the ones where their training occurred.  And those lower-rated programs have few (or none) of the vaunted research-only positions.

Comment: I got the impression that *any* faculty position comes with those 3 tasks, but the distribution of time expected may differ. I was wondering whether this change in distribution has an appreciable effect on the researcher's success / output.

Comment: @Dwagg How can the answer to that question be anything but "obviously yes"?

Comment: @BryanKrause see BrianH's response

Comment: @Dwagg The bulk of BrainH's response has to do with the distribution of teaching responsibilities in different institutions, which is important. The answer to your sub question "whether this change in distribution has an appreciable effect on the researcher's success / output" is trivially yes, both in my comment and in Brian's answer.

Comment: @BryanKrause I don't think it is *trivially* yes ;)